# Invoke-Command inconsistency

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is trying to run some commands on a remote server.  Can someone explain why I need to wrap the first line of my script block in parenthesis?  For example:

```powershell
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential:$username
$starter = New-PSSession -ComputerName VmProd01.ares.priv -Credential:$cred -Authentication CredSSP
Invoke-Command -Session $starter -ScriptBlock {
    echo 'Output 1'
    echo 'Output 2'
    echo 'Output 3'
    echo 'Output 4'
}
Remove-PSSession $starter
```

Will output "Output 1" and stop while this outputs everything

```powershell
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential:$username
$starter = New-PSSession -ComputerName VmProd01.ares.priv -Credential:$cred -Authentication CredSSP
Invoke-Command -Session $starter -ScriptBlock {
    (echo 'Output 1')
    echo 'Output 2'
    echo 'Output 3'
    echo 'Output 4'
}
Remove-PSSession $starter
```

My client is:

```powershell
PSVersion                      5.0.9883.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.4.9883.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

And the remote server is:

```powershell
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
PSVersion                      2.0
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
WSManStackVersion              2.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I should also add that when I added the echo $PSVersionTable as the first line of my remote script block to get the version here I also got all four output.  Have I stumbled on a bug in an older version of powershell, or is there some rule I need to apply elsewhere in powershell?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell is pretty smart, when it comes to parsing multiline formatting, but it looks like it failed this time. Try adding `;` after your `echo` statements:

```powershell
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential:$username
$starter = New-PSSession -ComputerName VmProd01.ares.priv -Credential:$cred -Authentication CredSSP
Invoke-Command -Session $starter -ScriptBlock {
    echo 'Output 1';
    echo 'Output 2';
    echo 'Output 3';
    echo 'Output 4';
}

Remove-PSSession $starter
```

**UPDATE:** More workarounds to try:

```powershell
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential:$username
$starter = New-PSSession -ComputerName VmProd01.ares.priv -Credential:$cred -Authentication CredSSP
Invoke-Command -Session $starter -ScriptBlock {Write-Host 'Output 1'; Write-Host 'Output 2'; Write-Host 'Output 3'; Write-Host 'Output 4';
}

Remove-PSSession $starter
```

```powershell
$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential:$username
$starter = New-PSSession -ComputerName VmProd01.ares.priv -Credential:$cred -Authentication CredSSP
Invoke-Command -Session $starter -ScriptBlock {
    $(Write-Host 'Output 1';
    Write-Host 'Output 2';
    Write-Host 'Output 3';
    Write-Host 'Output 4';)
}
```

Comment: When I add just the ; to each statement I still only get "Output 1".  Seems to require the parenthesis.

Comment: @Kleinux I've just checked and your code runs fine against remote machine with PS 3.0.Using parenthesis you force PS to evaluate expression and return object, so it seem that you've hit some obscure bug, and found a workaround. You could also try to wrap all your code inside scriptblock with `$()` and see if this helps (I've updated my answer).

Comment: I love it when I find obscure bugs :)  Thanks for the followup.  The funny thing is that my script ran fine for years until just recently, so this is something that must have broken in a recent update.

Comment: @Kleinux Looking at your `PSVersion` I see `5.0.9883.0` and this means [PS 5.0 November preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/11/18/windows-management-framework-5-0-preview-november-2014-is-now-available.aspx). So you can still report a bug to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell) and maybe it will be fixed in release version.